# getSegment matching category title

Tags: categories, getsegment

I'm trying to match the 2nd part of the slug with the category title to then place a 'current' class on the link.

Something like:

```
{% nav category in craft.categories.group('blogCategories') %}

    <a class="button button--outline-blue {% if craft.request.getSegment(2) == '{{ category.title }}' %}current{% endif %}" href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}</a>

{% endnav %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might do something like this, concerned that you want to set current on active category.

```
{% set categorySlug = craft.request.getLastSegment() %} 

{% nav category in craft.categories.group('blogCategories') %}
    {% set current = (category.slug == categorySlug) %}
    <a class="button button--outline-blue 
       {% if current %} current{% endif %}
       href="{{ category.url }}">
       {{ category.title }}
    </a>
{% endnav %}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's setting 'current' on all rather than just the one that matches the current slug.

Comment: You may try now.